# Python .. create a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

what is actually the following code doing?..
In particular, the index one...

For my understanding, 
for a "A,b = create_matrix_1(4,4)"
the matrix A is 16*16; b is 16*1

I am having some trouble understanding this problem. Any insight whatsoever would be appreciated

```
def create_matrix_1(n,m,force=0.0): 
    """ 
      Create a matrix associated with a tension force to a membrane. 
      The domain is represented by a 2D grid of size n*m 
    """ 

    hx = 1.0/(n-1) 
    hy = 1.0/(m-1) 

    hx2 = 1.0/hx**2 
    hy2 = 1.0/hy**2 

    x = linspace(0,1,n) 
    y = linspace(0,1,m) 

    A = lil_matrix((n*m, n*m)) 
    b = zeros(n*m) 
    for i in range(n): 
            for j in range(m): 
                    index = i + j*n 
                    if( i==0 or i==n-1 or j==0 or j==m-1): # Boundary nodes 
                            b[index] = saddle_function(x[i],y[j]) 
                            A[index,index] = 1.0 
                    else: # Interior Nodes 
                            b[index] = force 
                            A[index,index] = -2.0*(hx2 + hy2) 
                            A[index,index+1] = hx2 
                            A[index,index-1] = hx2 
                            A[index,index+n] = hy2 
                            A[index,index-n] = hy2 
    return A,b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For my understanding, for a "A,b = create_matrix_1(4,4)" the matrix A
>   is 16*16; b is 16*1

Not necessarily: in the code above we don't have the definitions of the functions `lil_matrix` and `zeros`. The statements before the `for` loop only say that `A` is equal to the value returned by the function `lil_matrix` when the values `(n*m, n*m)` are passed to it as a tuple. On the other hand `b` is equal to the value returned by the function `zeros`, when you pass to it `n*m`.

Then there is the loop section.
Basically, there are 2 nested loops, i.e. there are two iterators, i and j, that are incremented respectively from 0 to n-1 and from 0 to m-1; so, assuming n = 4 and m = 4:

1) We start by iterating through all values of `j`, having `i=0`:

```
Iteration    Value of index

1            0+0*4
2            0+1*4
3            0+2*4
4            0+3*4
```

2) Now that all `j` values, from `j=0` to `j=m-1`, have been cycled through, we increment `i`, and again we iterate through all values of `j`:

```
5            1+0*4
6            1+1*4
7            1+2*4
8            1+3*4
```

3) Then we repeat the same cycle for `i=2`, `i=3` etc., until `i=n-1`.

Now we get to the `if` and `else` blocks. For each of the cycles described above, if we have a boundary value, i.e. either `i` or `j` are at the first or last iteration of the cycle (e.g. either `i` or `j` are `= 0`, or `i=n-1` or `j=m-1`) then the values of `A` and `b` are not any more the ones described at the beginning of this answer, but are changed according to the two lines after the line starting with `if`. If instead the values of `i` or `j` are not boundary values, but are interior nodes, the values of `A` and `b` are changed according to the lines after the `else` statement.

Both the statements in the `if` and in the `else` section only change some of the elements of `A` and `b`, which are arrays. Looking at the code, `A` must be a bidimensional array (matrix), as you pointed out correctly in your question, and `b` is a one dimensional array (vector). (In Python, by the way, arrays are actually lists, but I will use here the general term array). Both in the `if` and `else` block we have the `index` keyword: e.g. `b[index]`means that the value of `b` that we are modifying is the Nth value of `b`, where `index` = N. For `A` we have two values in the square brackets, since `A` is a matrix. By the way there is in my opinion an error in the syntax since when you select a single value in a matrix you don't use the comma, e.g. you don't write `A[x, y]` but `A[x][y]` (the comma can only be used when you define the matrix, not when you select one of its values). However both `A` and `b` are created in the first place using functions not included in this code so we don't know much more than that.

Other than `lil_matrix` and `zeros`, the other function which you need to investigate, because its definition is not included in this code, is `linspace`: this is used at the beginning to create the variables `x` and `y` which then are used in the `if` block.